# Xamarin.Forms, Create clickable Frame (background)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, frame

As Button is limited to use images inside it in Xamarin.Forms And `StackLayout` does not support `CornerRadius` property, We decided to use `Frame` instead of them, the `Tapped` event is implemented but the problem is background does not change on clicking.
So how can I create and set a clickable background to frame?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't handle visual state in xamarin forms. But you can do something like below code to achieve the state transition using custom renderer.

```
public class CustomFrameRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FrameRenderer
{
    private Color backgroundColor;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        backgroundColor = Element.BackgroundColor;
        Control.Touch += Control_Touch;
    }

    private void Control_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Event.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                Element.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                Element.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Above code would affect all the frames so better subclass and create a new frame to avoid background color transition in the entire app.

Comment: what is the control there? frame doesnt implement any control?

Comment: Control is the cardview (Native element for Xamarin.forms Frame element)